# How to access a PHP project running on nginx server from another laptop - Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, networking

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and i have PHP project running on NGINX server and now i want access this project from another laptop or mobile.

On windows, i used to access that via IP address. how can i do that in Ubuntu ?

On my own laptop i access through a fake domain registered for my local machine. Check below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You can add the IP address of the Ubuntu laptop into your local hosts file (/etc/hosts I think) with the fake domain name.  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=3407

Comment: They bot are on the same network i guess?